# Set default language for a TextBox component in WPF application?

Tags: c#, .net, wpf

The people here are old, and they don't pay attention when using software application. That is why I was asked to set my text boxes with default language or locale, or however is called. 
This means, when somebody types on the keyboard with English letters(English locale set in system tray), the text box should convert the letters to Macedonian(mk-MK locale).

Is it possible to achieve this in WPF/C#/.NET 4 application and if yes how?
Which libraries do I need?

Comment: Could you just use a converter, perhaps?

Comment: Yes, it should be possible.... but have you considered what to do when people *want* to type English characters?

Comment: @xecollons converter? So develop custom code as I type change character encoding???

Comment: @Stefan well if it is possible to set different language to different textbox, than I have no problem? I have just two text boxes, one should accept only english letters and one only Macedonian. Everything else is just combobox, choosing already defined values.

Answer (score 0):

Try setting the locale via the InputLanguageManager:

```
InputLanguageManager.SetInputLanguage(yourTextBox, CultureInfo.CreateSpecificCulture("mk-MK"));
```

Obviously in order for this to work the mk-MK language must be installed via the Windows setup.